# OSMC, Bluetooth audio choppy

Tags: debian, raspberry-pi, alsa, bluetooth

I have a Raspberry Pi running OSMC, paired to a UE MEGABOOM speaker. As of lately, I am having issues with choppy audio. The issue is somewhat sporadic in nature – I may be able to play a few songs with no issues, then again the setup struggles to get even a single note over the ether. What I’ve tried:

- When I disconnect the speaker and play back audio through the HDMI output on the Pi, there are no issues – which rules out any network (or other non-Bluetooth) issue (the content is on another Pi and accesses via SMB).
- Audio is choppy even when the speaker is right next to the Pi (which is in a plastic enclosure), which should largely rule out signal strength issues.
- I also use other Bluetooth equipment (laptop with headset) in the same area, which works fine – which should rule out interference issues.
- Wifi is disabled, network connection is through the wired Ethernet adapter – which rules out resource conflicts between wifi and Bluetooth (which I have observed on other devices).

So now the software is my main suspect. This seems to have worsened over time, though I have not made any major changes to my setup, other than installing OSMC updates.

Running `top` on the Pi does not indicate any overload – `kodi.bin` is slightly above 30% processor load, `bluealsa` around 2–3%. Of 1 GB memory, around a quarter is used, half is buff/cache, a quarter is free (no swap memory is configured), both during normal playback and when audio is choppy. The Pi is a third-generation device.

What could be causing the issues? Where should I continue troubleshooting?